# Dutch citizenship after years

Tags: dual-citizenship, dutch-citizens

Is it possible to get the Dutch citizenship now having a Dutch mother and a German father and being born in 1978?
And if yes would your own children get the Dutch citizenship as well?

Comment: To know this a lot more details are required: have you lived in the Netherlands, and for how long? Were were you born? What is the nationality of the husband? etc.. See: https://www.government.nl/topics/dutch-nationality/contents/becoming-a-dutch-national

Comment: Husband is German.

Comment: Born in Germany. Living in NL now for 6 years.

Comment: Seems that you might be eligible for naturalisation, see if you meet the conditions: https://ind.nl/EN/individuals/residence-wizard/dutch-citizenship/naturalisation/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: Thanks. However that means that I'll have to renounce the current German nationality.

Comment: Yes, not so long ago they put this rule. And I don't see an [exception](https://ind.nl/EN/individuals/residence-wizard/Pages/renouncing-nationality-and-exceptions.aspx) which applies to your case. Maybe you can ask at the Dutch consulate in Germany.

Comment: @agold why wouldn't the option procedure apply ("You were born or adopted before 1 January 1985. Your (adoptive) mother is Dutch and your (adoptive) father is not (latent Dutch)")?

Comment: @phoog you might be right, but I don't know if this allows the OP to have a double nationality.